# Analyzing social preference data with 2 genotype combinations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I have two genotypes (A and B). Mice for each genotype undergo two experimental sessions:

1. exposure of the mice to an object and a mouse from the A genotype
2. exposure of the mice to an object and mouse from the B genotype

For each session you calculate the social preference ratio, which goes from 1 (the mouse explore only the other mouse) to -1 (the mouse explores only the object):

```
(time exploring the mouse - time exploring the object) /
total time of exploration
```

So in the end you end up with four measures:

- social preference ratio of mice A when exposed to object/mouse B
- social preference ratio of mice A when exposed to object/mouse A
- social preference ratio of mice B when exposed to object/mouse B
- social preference ratio of mice B when exposed to object/mouse A

With what statistical test would you compare these data results?

Our main question is if there are differences in social preferences in A mice versus B mice. Would it be preferable to analyse each pair-wise comparison separately, or could we fill a model with several contrasts such as:

- social preference of A vs B when exposed to object/A
- social preference of A vs B when exposed to object/B
- social preference of A vs B when exposed to the respective same genotype
- social preference of A vs B when exposed to the other genotype

Comment: Is the `total time of exploration` the same for all mice? For each observation of a pair of mice, are you gathering data for both mice, or only a predefined mouse from the dyad? Would it make any sense / is it possible for 1 mouse to only explore the other mouse & the other mouse to only explore the object, or does 1 mouse exploring the other pretty much mean that the other has to be exploring it as well? Are you running a given mouse through the experimental procedure more than once?

Answer (score 0):

May I point you to my recent paper which may help you to address this issue?

- Karl Schilling, John Oberdick and René L. Schilling.  Toward an Efficient and Integrative Analysis of Limited-Choice Behavioral Experiments.  *Journal of Neuroscience 12* September 2012, 32 (37) 12651-12656; DOI: https://doi.org/10.1523/JNEUROSCI.1452-12.2012

All the analyses outlined in that paper are readily implemented in R.

Comment: Can you give a precis of the information in the paper to help future readers decide if they want to pursue it?